# PHP with APC: Fatal errors: Cannot redeclare class

Tags: apc, php

Since I installed APC for PHP with PECL I get sometimes these errors: `Cannot redeclare class xxx`

xxx changes from time to time. I could disable APC but APC improves the performance great! Is there a known bug or could I do something else to prevent these errors? I'm using Ubuntu 8.04 LTS with PHP 5.2.4.

---

*Edit/Update (from comments):*

I use the Zend Framework Autoloader and these error never occurred before I enabled APC. A few moments ago I get for example that error: `Fatal error: require(): Cannot redeclare class zend_db_adapter_abstract in /paths/app/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 27`

Comment: Read the whole error message. Do not include the said file twice. Use `include_once`. Or failing that, wrap all definitions in `if (!class_defined("xxx")) {`

Comment: In addition to only using include_once, try and re-architect the application to make use of class autoloading, so that PHP will only include files when needed. Also stick to common-sense things, like one class per file, etc.

Comment: what do you mean by xxx? is xxx actually the class you want to load?

Comment: I use the Zend Framework Autoloader and these error never occurred before I enabled APC. A few moments ago I get for example that error: `Fatal error: require(): Cannot redeclare class zend_db_adapter_abstract in /paths/app/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 27`

Comment: What version of APC are you running?

Answer (score 13):

The combination of the following configs fixed it for me:

```
apc.include_once_override = 0
apc.canonicalize = 0
apc.stat = 0
```

Without all 3, I'd constantly get the error, but *with* all three I seem to no longer get the error :)!

Comment: These three are not working for me unfortunately (APC 3.1.13 and PHP 5.4.24 CentOS 6.5). With WordPress it is the Walker_Page class that it claims is being redeclared, even though the file is absolutely not being called up more than once. I'll dig deeper and see what I can find.

Comment: Sorry Jason, this worked with some older version of APC and PHP. I know for sure that the PHP version I was working with at the time was no newer than 5.3.*

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem with a bunch of PHP libraries as soon as I enabled APC. After a lot of hair pulling I found that setting `apc.include_once_override = 0` cleared things up.  Still monitoring but haven't had a the problem re-occur (before that I was able to induce the error by clearing the apc cache).

Answer (score 3):

This error happened when using Amazon's `AWS SDK` for `PHP2` in a php script running under `cron`. One solution was to disable `apc` via `-d apc.enabled=0` as shown below:

```
/usr/bin/php -d apc.enabled=0 /path/to/myshelljob.php
```

For [more info](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-appleosx-php-disable-apc-ini/).

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, seems to be a [common issue](http://www.google.com/search?q=Zend+Framework+Autoloader+APC+Cannot+redeclare+class):

- [Opcode (APC/XCache), Zend, Doctrine, and Autoloaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364750/opcode-apc-xcache-zend-doctrine-and-autoloaders)
- http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=813
- http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8588

What I just noticed from your specific error message is that you wrote `zend_db_adapter_abstract` in all-lowercase. A problem with the horrid framework naming schemes and autoloaders is that they keep files in mixed case and expect it so. If your code tried to instantiate it this way, the autoloader might not have found it. APC might be more peculiar here, since it overrides `include_once` internally, maybe with side-effects.

A solution would be to adapt the Zend autoloader, and manually keep a list of loaded classes and (absolute and lowercased) filenames to proofcheck in lieu of include_once.

Otherwise, try excessive xdebug-ing. Without access to your setup, all we can do is guess here.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is a known problem with apc that it mixes up `include_once` directivse that are called relatively from different locations.

So if you do `include_once myclass.php` and then in a subdirectory do `include_once ../myclass.php` apc could mix this up and think its different files and loads it twice.

However this is fixed in later versions.

If you can drill down your code to the class that is loaded twice you could do some checking if the class is already loaded with `class_defined` or some callable stuff.

You can also use the `apc.filter` directive to prevent certain files from beeing cached at all.

Comment: well the problem stays the same. upgrade your apc version and/or zend framework or you either have to patch your zend framework, there are solutions available on the zend issue tracker or maby you can catch the exception in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Download the [latest apc](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/apc/) version and use:

```
[APC]
apc.cache_by_default = 0
```

With apc.stat = 0 the server loads the php files in cache, if you modify it, php still loads the same.

More info:

- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58878#1275406932
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen to me, and I didn't find the solution suggested in any of the other answers. I am using various autoloaders including Composer autoloader and an older version of the Zend Framework Autoloader.

The problem turned out to be caused by a slight name mismatch between the file name and the class name. One character different between the class name and the file name - a discrepancy that a human could easily miss but the a couple of autoloaders successively `include`d the same file, causing the error.