# APC opcode cache breaks application

Tags: php, zend-framework, deployment, apc, composer-php

I use composer to install Zend Framework 2 and other libraries. Every time after re-installing an application in the same path, I have to manually clear the APC (version 3.1.13) opcode cache (with PHP 5.4.8), otherwise I get errors like

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Zend\\Mvc\\ApplicationInterface' not found
```

or

```
PHP Fatal error:  include(): Cannot redeclare class zend\\eventmanager\\eventscapableinterface
```

The failing class keeps changing after every application install. I have [apc.stat=1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat), so the opcode cache should notice newly deployed php files and recompile them automatically, if I have deployed the application on the same path before.

I have discussed the problem on Github with the composer developers and posted my APC settings here: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1662. We agree that this looks more like an APC problem.

Comment: I guess I could automatize APC opcode cache clearing using the somewhat complicated solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3580939/94289. But I hope there's some easier fix.

Comment: `touch` all your updated files so they have a new timestamp, `apc` is pretty dumb.

Comment: I've seen somewhere on mailing list that there are problems with APC and PHP5.4, unfortunately I can't find it, to see what exactly was said.

Comment: Does this question help at all? [PHP with APC: Fatal errors: Cannot redeclare class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575341/php-with-apc-fatal-errors-cannot-redeclare-class) ... one suggestion is to try changing `apc.include_once_override = 0`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!
@SimonHampel I already have `apc.include_once_override = 0`, see [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1662#issuecomment-14458750).
@ZdenekMachek I'll try but since I delete the whole vendor folder (containing Zend Framework) upon reinstall and then install the contents again (from composer cache), I think the file timestamps should be updated automatically..

Comment: @Wrikken: thanks, touching all files indeed fixes the problem:
`find . -exec touch {} \;`
If you like, provide this as an answer so I can accept and upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

I think that is `include_path` setted up twice. When `include_path` called twice it will make confusing to APC reading and parsing. Make sure that your ZEND project are not called twice on `include_path`.

And another checkout that you are properly configure ini settings or put manually ini settings data:

```
apc.include_once_override = 0
apc.canonicalize = 0
apc.stat = 0
```

In meanwhile this issue can be already solved due to updates.